# Find NFA for this language

Tags: state-machine, nfa

I've constructed the NFA (non deterministic finite automaton) for this language L = (aa*b) ∪ b ∪ (aab)*

Is it correct? I'm not really sure with the Epsilon-transitions.

[image]

Comment: You can combine `q9` with `q10` and you can combine `q4` with `q7`.

Comment: True, thanks. And then it's correct?

Comment: It is already correct.